# What does the $ symbol do in VBA?

Tags: vba, types

For example:

```
variable1=Dir$(some_path)
```

vs.

```
variable1=Dir(some_path)
```

What is the difference?

Why not just do:

```
variable1=string(Dir(some_path))
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

**Here is a Cheat Sheet for DataTypes**

Variable End with:

```
$ : String
% : Integer (Int16)
& : Long (Int32)
! : Single
# : Double
@ : Decimal
```

Start with:

```
&H : Hex
&O : Octal
```

Comparison between VB and VB.Net ([reference](http://www.aivosto.com/vbtips/datatypes.html))

Visual Studio .Net added Literal Types ([reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/type-characters))

Value End with: (For more complete list, refer the the reference)

```
S : Short (Int16)
I : Integer (Int32)
L : Long (Int64)
F : Single
R : Double
D : Decimal
```

Answer (score 16):

I think that the `$` version returns a `String`, and the non `$` version returns a `variant`.

[Mid vs Mid$](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519579/mid-vs-mid)

http://forums.devarticles.com/microsoft-access-development-49/mid-function-vs-mid-26315.html

Comment: why not just do:

variable1=string(Dir(some_path))

Comment: ***Let's find out:*** `Debug.Print TypeName(Mid("abc", 2, 1))` returns `String`, *and* `Debug.Print TypeName(Mid$("abc", 2, 1))` **also** returns `String`. On the other hand, there's [**this**](https://i.imgur.com/5KroAb8.png).

Answer (score 9):

The dollar sign indicates a string will be returned instead of a variant.

Comment: why not just do:

variable1=string(Dir(some_path))

Answer (score 3):

Dir() returns the result as the variant data type. Dir$() returns the result as the string data type.

Answer (score 0):

some uses $ version for its purported efficiency(as it accepts and outputs statically-typed variables only). I don't know how much is the speed difference between statically-typed and variant type, just benchmark

Comment: So why not test it rather than post an answer that is ambiguous as to whether you believe there is a benefit (purportedly) but then makes clear you don't know? :)

Comment: @brettdj I know $ version functions are faster than non-dollar(accepts variant parameter), but didn't know the speed in speed could be staggering for *millions* of iterations. Never I done something in a loop, just letting the database do the heavy lifting, perhaps if I'm a component maker I can appreciate the efficiency of $%&!#@ (I'm not cursing eh lol) version functions. For some, it is a purported efficiency; but for some, the efficiency is real and tangible. Here's a sample benchmark http://www.shamrock-software.eu/vb.htm

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7982220/differentiate-trim-and-trim-in-vba/7988125#7988125

Comment: @MichaelBuen "i'm not cursing" :D