# What's the difference between Trim() and Trim$() in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, trim

What is the difference between `trim` and `trim$` in vba? Accidentally today when I used left and trim functions in vba, The compiler said `cant find project or library`

When I googled it ,On one of the forum I found the user using like these

```
 vba.trim("string")
```

He answered to prefix with vba for the functions. and surprisingly it worked on my pc too.But I found these functions

```
 trim and trim$ 
 left and left$ 
 leftb and leftb$
```

I was wondering what is trim and trim$. I wanted to find the difference So I started to google it but the results are for trim ignoring the $ alphabet.

I'm just curious to know about it.I was suspecting that trim is vba function and trim$ is excel sheet function. But we have `Application.worksheetfunction` to use excel functions right?Could anyone differentiate trim and trim$.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389444/vba-what-does-do

Answer (score 24, accepted):

While Issun has answered your question as asked I had enough detail that I wanted to post to provide a further answer as opposed to comment.

The string versions **are** significantly faster ~ approx 10-30% depending on the data type from my testing over the years. While this is not normally noticeable, it is a performance difference when running on large datasets. So for me it's a no-brainer to use the string rather than variant version.

The sample below works on strings so it shows a speed advantage at the higher end of this range

I have used these functions in combination with variant arrays in both of my [public addins](http://www.experts-exchange.com/A_2613.html) as these programs are typically used on entire worksheets even entire workbooks

[This link](http://www.aivosto.com/vbtips/stringopt.html#variant) is an excellent reference, for your question, and well beyond

1. Comparing in `vbBinaryCompare` rather than `vbTextCompare`
2. Optimising empty strings
3. Testing before replacing
4. Using built in constants, `VbNullString` is faster than `""`, although both will miss a cell that contains `'` whereas `IsEmpty` picks this up
5. Optimising Loops (break `AND` into two separate `IF`s to give an early escape)
6. Optimising If tests to return the most common Boolean result first rather than run through the `Else` path (ie a `False` test may be more appropriate than `True`)
7. Using `Mid$` on the left hand side of an assignment. From [hidden features of VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1338833/641067)

   ```
   Sub QuickTimer1()
   Dim lngRow As Long
   Dim dbTime As Double
   Dim strSample As String
   Dim strShort As String
   strSample = "random string"
   dbTime = Timer()
   For lngRow = 1 To 50000000
       strShort = Left$(strSample, 6)
   Next lngRow
   MsgBox Timer() - dbTime
   End Sub

   Sub QuickTimer2()
   Dim lngRow As Long
   Dim dbTime As Double
   Dim strSample As String
   Dim strShort As String
   strSample = "random string"
   dbTime = Timer()
   For lngRow = 1 To 50000000
       strShort = Left(strSample, 6)
   Next lngRow
   MsgBox Timer() - dbTime
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: The only reason to accept your answer is that link ! it really helped me brettdj Thanks alot! I was using "" and instr left functions very often now i came to know how a good programmer differs from a normal programmer!

Comment: Im really impressed with your help , Do you have some more links , Could you suggest me some ? I dont find good articles .

Comment: Niko, not really, this article is an absolute standout. I know you are already well versed in variant arrays as well. I think the next best option for you would be to browse the posts at [Dicks Blog](http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com), I have a longer listing of helpful sites here http://stackoverflow.com/q/7523102/641067

Comment: Your expertsExchange article advises not to use array formulas, but doesn't say why. Array formulas are one of the most powerful Excel features, and i often use them in VBA. They can process a huge array in a single statement. They execute much faster than something i could put into a VBA loop.

Answer (score 11):

**`Trim`** is the variant version. If you use it on a string, it will need to do an unnecessary conversion.

**`Trim$`** is the string version. Use this if you are using it on a string.

Fun side note: The `Application.WorksheetFunction` version of `Trim` does something different than VBA's Trim function.

It's worth noting that **Left/Left$, Mid/Mid$, Right/Right$** have variant/string versions as well. In functions that loop or use these often, you *will* notice a performance hit if you use the variant version, although with modern PCs it's not huge, but it's still arguably good practice to not do something when you know it'll cause an extra step you don't need.

Comment: Performance hit isn't just about multi-second delays on large datasets. Even minor latencies during mouseclicks or typing are noticeable for users. If you're using 10 functions after a click and they each contribute a tiny amount to the delay, users will subconsciously notice it. The application will feel less responsive. "the minimal
perceivable latency rests anywhere between 2 ms and 100 ms" https://www.tactuallabs.com/papers/howMuchFasterIsFastEnoughCHI15.pdf . 2 ms is 1/500th of a second!

Answer (score 5):

`trim` accepts a variant as its parameter while `trim$` accepts a string.

There are some performance benefits for using trim$ (since you aren't converting from a variant), but chances are you wouldn't notice them.

EDIT:

I figured this out by checking the object browser. When you are in the VBA editor, press F2 and you can search for functions and be come more familiar with the framework.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the notation is a legacy of VB days, where $ was used to denote objects/functions that were (or operated on) strings.

Functionally, there's no difference although I understand that the `$` version is [alleged to be faster](http://www.xoc.net/standards/rvbacc.asp#DollarSignFunctions), as it eliminates the need to convert from a variant to a string.