# Copy Text and make it upper case

Tags: excel, uppercase, vba

I am trying to create a macro that the user will enter their initials in a specific cell and the macro will copy the initials and paste them into a list on another tab. I am having a hard time figuring out how to convert it over to upper case any help is greatly appreciated below is my code. Thanks in advance!

```
    'By Initials
    Worksheets("New PN").Activate
        Range("B10").Copy
        Sheets("PN_List").Select
        Range("F1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Selection.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

        With Selection.Font
    .Name = "Calibri"
    .Size = 11

End With
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for the fast response. If you wouldn't mind showing me the whole formula with the added part I would appreciate it

Comment: As per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7982220/differentiate-trim-and-trim-in-vba/7988125#7988125 the string version of `UCase$` is faster than the variant version `UCase`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the UCASE function.  this works for me

```
   ActiveCell = UCase(ActiveCell)
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I wanted! Your the best!

Answer (score 1):

- right-click your sheet tab *PN New*
- View Code
- copy and paste the code below

This code will then *automatically* add any new value/s from `B10` and `B12` (second cell used as an example so the code can run on a range if needed) into the first blank cell in column F on sheet *PN_List*

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim rng3 As Range
Dim lngCnt As Long

Set rng1 = Intersect(Range("B10,B12"), Target)
If rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Set rng3 = Sheets("PN_List").Columns("F:F").Find("*", Sheets("PN_List").[f1], xlValues, , xlPrevious, xlByRows)
If rng3 Is Nothing Then Set rng3 = Sheets("PN_List").[f1]
For Each rng2 In rng1
rng3.Offset(lngCnt + 1, 0) = UCase$(rng2)
lngCnt = lngCnt + 1
Next rng2
End Sub
```

Comment: plus one, for covering all what the OP wants. a little bit advance  logic though. :D

Answer (score 0):

Use `Ucase` function like this:

```
Dim initial as String

initial = Ucase(Range("B10").Value)
Range("F1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = initial
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello and thank you for the fast response. If you wouldn't mind showing me the whole formula with the added part I would appreciate it

Comment: I think brettdj already covered the most part for you. :) but what do you mean by `showing me the whole formula with the added part`?