# Excel VBA Cell Formatting, If Statemets

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet that is used for sales entry, that has 15 different columns that get formatted based on what is entered in the cell. It's simple formatting, converting to proper case, things like that.

The shortened version of the code is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
On Error GoTo Cleanup
Application.EnableEvents = False: Application.ScreenUpdating = False: 
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual ' etc..

Dim rName As String
If Not (Application.Intersect(target, Range("C2:C" & Me.Cells(Me.Rows.Count,"C").End(xlDown).Row)) Is Nothing) Then
    rName = target.Value2
    target.Value2 = UCase(Trim(rName))
End If

14x more above the above (1 each column)

Cleanup:
Application.EnableEvents = True: Application.ScreenUpdating = True: 
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic ' etc..
```

The reason I have it set to manual, then automatic, is because if I don't, Excel crawls to a halt. I'm assuming because when a user enters data, it changes values for hidden columns, and triggers the Change event again. The way it works now, is fine, however there is just a second or two delay after each cell is checked and formatted after a user enters the data, so ultimately I'm wondering if there is a quicker way to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: Might be safer to find the last cell by coming up from the bottom of the sheet not going down. Avoids hitting the bottom of the sheet if nothing present in that column. You don't need the Me.

Answer (score 2):

One obvious issues:

- `Me.Cells(Me.Rows.Count,"C").End(`**`xlDown`**`).Row    'returns row 1,048,576`

should be

- `Me.Cells(Me.Rows.Count,"C").End(`**`xlUp`**`).Row`

Try this:

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.CountLarge = 1 Then

        If Not (Application.Intersect(Target, Me.UsedRange.Columns("C")) Is Nothing) Then

            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual ' etc..
                On Error Resume Next
                Target.Value2 = UCase$(Trim$(Target.Value2))
                On Error GoTo 0
            Application.EnableEvents = True
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic ' etc..

        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

---

Notes:

- turning Off and On Application.ScreenUpdating takes longer than updating the cell
- [String versions (Trim$) are significantly faster ~ approx 10-30%..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7982220/whats-the-difference-between-trim-and-trim-in-vba#7988125), and [so is UCase$()](http://www.aivosto.com/vbtips/stringopt.html#variant)

Comment: Thanks for the introduction to CountLarge! Does the use of Me add anything here? And does Trim$ over Trim produce any enhancement of note? Genuine questions.

Comment: @QHarr: `Target.Count` is like using Int for variables - it will error out if the user selects the entire sheet (left-upper corner). `Target.CountLarge` can handle all cells on the sheet (similar to using Long to accommodate all rows).`Me` doesn't add to performance, it just makes it explicit

Comment: Good point: [_"The string versions (Trim$) are significantly faster ~ approx 10-30%..."_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7982220/whats-the-difference-between-trim-and-trim-in-vba#7988125), and [so is UCase$()](http://www.aivosto.com/vbtips/stringopt.html#variant); Updated the answer as well

Comment: While it didn't immediately solve the problem, it did teach me some new things, so thanks. It would seem its not related to the Change event. I removed it entirely, and even after changing something in those cells, the delay remains. Some columns have the delay and some don't, so going to remove one by one and see if I can find the culprit slowing it down.

Answer (score 1):

Try your intersect as,

```
If Not Application.Intersect(target, target.parent.usedrange) Is Nothing Then
```

The worksheet's .UsedRange property is decided beforehand. If you made an entry outside the usedrange, the usedrange would instantly expand to encompass it. This known as 'overhead' and it's one of the reasons that vba is slower than C or hex.

After you've determined that one or more cells in target is involved with something you want to do, parse each cell in target to determine how it should be processed.

Comment: being in a worksheet code pane, `target.parent.usedrange` can be reduced to `UsedRange`

Answer (score 0):

you may try this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
    If Intersect(target, Columns("C:Q")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' exit if changed cells are completely outside relevant columns (change "C:Q" to your actual relevant columns indexes)

    Application.EnableEvents = False: Application.ScreenUpdating = False:
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual ' etc..
    On Error GoTo Cleanup

    With Intersect(target, Intersect(UsedRange, Columns("C:Q"))) 'consider only changed cells in relevant columns (change "C:Q" to your actual relevant columns indexes)
        .Value2 = UCase(Trim(.Value2))
    End With

Cleanup:
    Application.EnableEvents = True: Application.ScreenUpdating = True:
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic ' etc..
End Sub
```