# VBA - Loop through folder with blank spaces address

Tags: vba, directory

I have a function that asks the user to select a folder and then another one that should output all the file names in that folder.
I have been trying the following but it does not work because the folder address contains blank spaces. Could you please help?

```
'gets folder address
recsFolder = Functions.GetFolder("C:\")

'Loop through files in folder
Dim StrFile As String
StrFile = Dir(recsFolder)
Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
    Debug.Print StrFile
    StrFile = Dir
Loop
```

Thanks!

Edit:
Code for GetFolder

```
Function GetFolder(strPath As String) As String
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = strPath
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
    NextCode:
    GetFolder = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing
End Function
```

By blank spaces I mean spaces that are present in the address (i.e. between Daily and Summary)
C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Daily Summary

Comment: What's the code for the `GetFolder` function? and what are "blank spaces" ?

Comment: @MacroMan please see the edited post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
StrFile = Dir(recsFolder)
```

To

```
StrFile = Dir(recsFolder & "\*.*")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide `Dir()` with a file pattern in order to list files.

Change to:

```
StrFile = Dir$(recsFolder & "\*.*")
```

Comment: cheers, it did work as well. What is the purpose of the $ after the Dir?

Comment: See [vba: what does $ do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389444/vba-what-does-do)

Comment: @peetman as a follow-on, the accepted answer on that link is useful - but isn't actually the reason why the `$` is used. A couple of answers down explains why: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3389455/4240221

Comment: @MacroMan thank you for the explanations. it returns a string.

Comment: Guys, I am having another issue. While the loop is running at some point the Dir gets the value <Invalid procedure call or argument>. How can I avoid this?

Comment: Probably best to ask a new question with the offending code & details.