# Is it possible to create a function that returns an object?

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a macro which will require referencing a large number of named ranges using:

```
ThisWorkbook.Names("$NAMEDRANGE$").RefersToRange.$METHOD$
```

I thought it might make the code easier to read/work with if I could create a function which I could use as follows:

```
NamedRange("$NAMEDRANGE$").$METHOD$
```

Without really knowing if it would work, I tried the following:

```
Function NamedRange(ByVal sName As String) As Object
    return ThisWorkbook.Names(sName).RefersToRange

End Function
```

This won't even compile, producing an

> Expected: end of statement

I think I may need to use a Class Module, but I'm not very familiar with them. Is this possible, or should I just spell out the entire reference on each line?

---

I have been spending too much time in C. This code works perfectly:

```
Function NamedRange(ByVal sName As String) As Object
   Set NamedRange = ThisWorkbook.Names(sName).RefersToRange

End Function
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I suggest first researching the msdn documentation on NamedRanges and Functions. NamedRanges require a Name and an address for the RefersToRange. In VBA we do not use the return keyword for returning something from a function. Also, the $ I think is meaningless here.

Comment: And yes to return an object from a function then Public Function myFunc(args....) As Object

Comment: Names is a collection at workbook level. You iterate those to get the properties information associated with a given name. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: This was a brain fart, I've been working a LOT in C lately. I'll edit my question to include the working code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about some of your syntax (are you combining languages?), but to answer your question...

**Yes, a VBA function can return an object.**

You just have to make sure it's properly declared and that the return value is `Set`, like any time an object is assigned to a variable.

```
Function myFunction() As Worksheet
    Set myFunction = Worksheets("Sheet1")
End Function

Sub myTest()
    Debug.Print myFunction.Name
End Sub
```

I'm not aware of `return` being used in this sense in VBA, nor the `$` dollar signs.  (The `$` can be used as a [shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19365070/8112776) to specify a String data type.)

Comment: Too much time in C lately, haha. This really helped, thank you!

Comment: @Skoddie -  Ah - that i understand - I often hesitate when switching between languages.  The `;` in js are my nemesis when switching to another language.

Answer (score 3):

The `Return` statement does exist in VBA, but it's used in conjunction with the antiquated `GoSub` statement, from a time before `Sub` and `Function` scopes were a thing - cue QBasic memories...

```
    foo = 42
    GoSub Increment
    Debug.Print foo ' prints 43
    Exit Sub
Increment:
    foo = foo + 1
    Return
```

So VBA is really expecting the statement to end immediately follownig the `Return` token, hence the "Expected: end of statement" error.

That's not what you want here. In VBA, the return value of `Function` (and `Property Get`) members is assigned by literally assigning to the member identifier:

```
Function GetFoo() As Long
    GetFoo = 42
End Function
```

And since you're returning an object reference, the `Set` keyword is required:

```
Function GetBar() As Something
    Set GetBar = New Something
End Function
```

Note that doing that *does not immediately return* to the caller - if you need to exit the function scope immediately, you need to `Exit Function` explcitly.

Comment: Ack, I realized this a split second before you posted haha. Too much time in C lately. Thank you!