# Builtin string functions with $

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any difference between using a builtin function returning a string such as `Left` or using the same function with a `$` appended (`Left$`)?

The output of this:

```
Debug.Print Left("Foo", 2)
Debug.Print Left$("Foo", 2)
```

is always

```
Fo
Fo
```

I suspect that it's strictly the same thing and that the `$` versions exist only for some compatibility reasons.

Comment: Well this might be useful https://stackoverflow.com/a/19365070/5811078

Comment: With `x = Left(a, b)` both `x` and `a` are variants compared to `Left$()` where both are `string`.

Comment: The $ variety (e.g. Left$, Mid$, etc) are measurably faster that their non-$ equivalents. Worth pursuing if you are doing hundreds of thousands of iterations or calculations.

Comment: @ScottCraner My bad - I was looking at the accepted answer (which doesn't answer the question).

Comment: @ScottCraner the linked duplicate has a highly-voted answer that is all about *type hints*, which have absolutely nothing to do with `Left`/`Left$` function aliases.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon but the other answers all say the same thing as the accepted answer below. And anyone that disagrees can certainly vote to reopen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The typed functions (those ending with a `$`) return a `String`. The un-typed versions return a `Variant`. Internally, these are handled by a pair of different functions (in the case of `Left`, it is `_B_str_Left` and `_B_var_Left`).

If you are assigning the return value to a `String` or a parameter expecting a `String`, using the typed version (`Left$`) avoids an implicit cast to a `Variant`. Similarly, if you're assigning to a `Variant`, using the un-typed version avoids a cast.

Comment: Worth noting that while the string function is *usually* preferable, `Left$` will blow up with a type mismatch given a `Null`, whereas `Left` will happily take it (well, and then blow up with another error because obviously you can't get the N left-most characters of a `Null` value, but consider `UCase`/`UCase$` then) - `Null` would only be relevant in a very limited number of scenarios outside of MS-Access.

Answer (score 3):

Left$() wants a string as argument but Left() expects a variant. Therefore using Left$() is faster if you know you will always pass it a string.

Comment: But this works too: `x = Left$(123, 2)` (result = `12`). That means that `123` is implicitely converted to string. Can you confirm?

Comment: @Jabberwocky VBA does type coercion / implicit type conversions liberally. `123` is definitely implicitly converted to a `String`, *it has to be*, for the signature of `Left$` takes a `String` parameter.